# Using SVG as converted to vector into imageview

Tags: android, svg, android-imageview

After design this below text in Inkscape application I would like to use it in Android into special `ImageView`

[image]

I am a beginner to use this feature in Android IFAIG I convert that on this link as:

http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

Now, after converting that I copy that into `drawable` folder and I assign that into `ImageView` I don't have this font structure in ImageView and that like with this image:

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You can directly use svg file in Android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your SVG file depends on a particular font being installed. Whether you convert the SVG using the online tool or whether you use it directly as proposed by *GianhTran*, it's better to remove this dependency.

So in Inkscape:

- Select the text
- Apply *Path > Object to Path* from the menu

Your text has now been converted into a path. It no longer depends on the font being present.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `svg` resource file, you can be using for `ImageView`,

Add below config into your `gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
       ....
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       ...
    }
```

And use `srcCompat` in `ImageView`

```
app:srcCompat="your_svg"
```